# Staking when you have 0 ETH

Tags: proof-of-stake, staking, validators

I was wondering how could you become a validator (and get ETH reward) **if it is required to have 32 ETH**?

Is it supposed that you bought 32ETH already? Or will there be another way to get ETH?

Couldn't find an answer on [ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/)

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Another question would be: How a blockchain based on PoS can be initialized if nobody has the coin to become a Validator?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no replacement to mining in a way that you can get Ether when you don't have any already. However, you don't really need the 32 ETH to participate in the PoS process and get rewarded. It is possible to build staking pool just like mining pools nowadays where you can participate with less ETH.

Comment: Yes I know about pool, but it's means that you already have >0 ETH.
My question is about when you have 0 ETH...
But thanks for your answer. 

Comment: @Amo sorry no chance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to buy 32 ETH from somewhere.

Perhaps from an exchange like Coinbase.

Or you're given ETH for some work you do in the ecosystem. Or you trade for some ETH.

There are plenty of ways to get ETH.

Comment: So how a blockchain based on PoS could be initialized if nobody has coins to become a Validator?

Comment: There is always an initial supply and an initial sale of where those tokens go to